# Hybris Commerce ERR SSL VERSION OR CIPHER MISMATCH

Tags: java, tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud

I have created a certificate with OpenSSL

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias server.key -file server.crt -keystore
```

and placed keystore.jks into `${catalina.home}/lib/`

server.xml

```
<Connector port="9002"
                          maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                          maxPostSize="4194304"
              maxThreads="150"
              protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
              executor="hybrisExecutor"
              enableLookups="false"
              acceptCount="100"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              disableUploadTimeout="true"
              URIEncoding="UTF-8"
              SSLEnabled="true"
                                       scheme="https"
                                       secure="true"
                                       clientAuth="false"
                               sslProtocol = "TLS"
                               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"

                               keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/lib/keystore.jks"
                               keystorePass="123456"
```

On Chrome it gives following error:

> ```
> This site can’t provide a secure connection
> 13.236.191.242 uses an unsupported protocol.
> ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
>
> Unsupported protocol
> The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
> ```

```
curl -Iv https://11.231.191.212:9001/

Trying 11.231.191.212...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to 11.231.191.212 (11.231.191.212) port 9001 (#0)
schannel: SSL/TLS connection with 11.231.191.212 port 9001 (step 1/3)
schannel: checking server certificate revocation
schannel: using IP address, SNI is not supported by OS.
schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 156 bytes...
schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 156 bytes
schannel: SSL/TLS connection with 11.231.191.212 port 9001 (step 2/3)
schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
```

Comment: Your server does not support the cipher suite or the TLS-version you used for creating your certificate. This means either your server is not up-to-date or you created certificates with old tls/cs.

Comment: so I have to re-create certificate with the supported TLS-version.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was creating a Self-signed certificate with OpenSSL. But when I generated the certificate from java Keystore then it works perfectly.

```
keytool.exe -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore c:\tomcatkeys
```

The reason was OpenSSL and keystore produce certificate in different file formats. You see the difference from the link below.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98282/difference-between-openssl-and-keytool